# assign unique id to <input> button and read it using jquery

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal

I have a minor problem, basically I have a hidden input button which is loaded with a unique value from a database table: `<input type="hidden" name="ProductId" class="ProductId" value='.$row["ProductId"].' />` This button gets repeated according to how many rows are returned through this method:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    echo '<table class="cart-row" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">';
    echo '<tbody>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td width="75"><img border="0" width="59px" height="78px" title="" alt="" src=' . $row["ImagePath"] .'></td>';
    echo '<td width="203"><span class="itemElements itemName">'. $row["Name"] .'</span></td>';
    echo '<td width="203"><input type="submit" class="btnMinus linkbtnType2" value="-"><input type="submit" class="btnPlus linkbtnType2" value="+"></td>';
    echo '<td width="135"><span class="qtyNum">('. $row["Qty"] .')</span> <br />';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="ProductId" class="ProductId" value='.$row["ProductId"].' />';
    echo '<span class="qtyRemoveLink"><input type="submit" class="btnRemove linkbtn" value="Remove"></td>';                            
    echo '<td width="180"><span class="itemElements orderStatus">In Stock Usually dispatched within 24 hours</span></td>';
    echo '<td width="175" class="itemPriceRow"><span id="itemPrice">€ '. $row["Price"] .'</span></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
    echo '<br>';                            
}
```

Im using a jQuery method to use read this value from the hidden button however it is only reading the value from the first input button generated. I tried changing the the button from an ID to a class but with no luck.

This is the jQuery method:

```
$('.btnRemove').click(function() {
    var productId = $(".ProductId").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "functions/deleteCartItem.php",
        data: "productId="+productId+ "",
        success: function(msg){   
            alert(msg);
        }
    })
})
```

A possible solution I can think of is to add a unique `id` to each button so they can be identified not only by name but also by `id`. However this poses a problem in reading it from the jQuery method.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
var productId = $(this).closest('tr').find(".ProductId").val();
```

`this` referring to `$('.btnRemove')` as DOM element.

`jQuery(this).closest("tr")` we are traveling up the DOM tree searching for the first `tr` element.

From here we search for `.ProductId`.

Andreas

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your assumption that it is because you are referencing by class which is causing the problem. Your `var productId = $(".ProductId").val();` will return an array of all the `.ProductId` elements, and `val()` will just return the value of the first of these.

To fix this you need to get the `.ProductId` element which is in the same container as the `.btnRemove` element which caused the click event, like this:

```
$('.btnRemove').click(function() {
    var productId = $(this).closest("td").find(".ProductId").val(); // amended selector
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "functions/deleteCartItem.php",
        data: "productId="+productId+ "",
        success: function(msg){   
            alert(msg);
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

it will not return the correct value, try something like

```
var productId = $(this).parent().find(".ProductId").val();
```

or

```
var productId = $(this).parent().children(".ProductId").val();
```

or

```
var productId = $(this).prev(".ProductId").val();
```

or

```
var productId = $(this).siblings(".ProductId").val();
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fwM3T/

Comment: `closest` will only deal with parents, and instead of your second version, `siblings` is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
 var productId = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name=ProductId]").val();
```